# Exponential distribution question

Tags: self-study, exponential-distribution

Let X and Y be independent exponential random variables with respective rate $\lambda$ and $\mu$ let **c** be a positive constant.

I want to find out a) $E[min(X,Y)|X>c]$

b)$E[min(X,Y)|X>Y+c]$ by a direct computation

c)I want to argue that, conditional on $X>Y$, the random variables $(X,Y)$ and$(X-Y)$ are independent.

d) Lastly, I want to conclude that

$E[min(X,Y)|X>Y+c]=E[min(X,Y)|X>Y]=\frac{1}{\lambda+\mu}$

Solution: I know probability density function,distribution function,mean, variance, mgf of exponential distribution. I also know  properties of exponential distribution such as memoryless property and other one is $P[min X_i>x]=exp{-\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mu_ix}$

Now how shall I proceed to answer these questions?

Comment: Well, to begin with, $$E(\min(X,Y)\mathbf 1_{X>c})=\int_c^\infty f_X(x)\int_0^xyf_Y(y)dydx+\int_c^\infty xf_X(x)\int_x^\infty f_Y(y)dydx=\ldots$$ Can you continue?

Comment: [a list of post about memoryless property with answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=memoryless++answers%3A1).